# How to authorize by role users from a parent Windows domain in ASP.NET MVC application, which is hosted in a child Windows domain?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have an **ASP.NET MVC 5** web application. It is hosted on **IIS 8.5** on **Windows Server 2012 R2** in a **Windows Intranet** environment. The web application leverages **Integrated Windows Authentication and Authorization** (all others authentication features are disabled).

There is a **Windows Domain** in the environment named **`MainDomain`**. In this domain there is a **Active Directory Group** of users **`AppUsers`** (**`MainDomain\AppUsers`**), which is used to authorize users upon accessing the web application's resources.

The web application itself is being hosted under a child domain **`ChildDomain`** (**`ChildDomain.MainDomain`**).

**Role-based authorization** is used in the code of the controllers. It looks like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"MainDomain\AppUsers")]
public HomeController : Controller
{
    // Action methods and other stuff...
}
```

I've run into a problem: any request (to any action method of the controller above) from any user, which is definitely belongs to **`MainDomain\AppUsers`** become unauthorized.

When the host was in **`MainDomain`** everything worked fine. But after the host was moved to **`ChildDomain`** (**`ChildDomain.MainDomain`**), the issue occured.

How to resolve that?